# Is there a way to launch the "SKSE" skyrim mod with the default Skyrim Launcher?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, mods

I got the "SKSE" and "SkyUI" mod for Skyrim, but launching Skyrim causes errors. SKSE has a special launcher that you need to use, but is there any way to launch SKSE from the default launcher, or must I use SKSE's custom launcher?

(Can I make the "Play" button in Skyrim launch the SKSE program instead of it's own program?)

Comment: SKSE is a 3rd party launcher. There is no way the official launcher knows about its existence.

Comment: @Nolor I can imagine (though I don't think it is the case) that the Play button might use a registry entry to know what to launch which could be changed, or you could do tricks with renaming .exes, so it's not so obviously a bad question. (*Why* anyone would want to use the garbage default launcher is a mystery to me though.)

Comment: I recommend using the [Nexus Mod Manager](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/modmanager/) to manage mods and launch SKSE, instead of the default Skyrim launcher. [There is an issue where the default Skyrim launcher might mess up the load order of the mods.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/109758/4797)

Comment: @avestar101 Since you were able to install SKSE, I assume that you know where the skyrim folder is. Renaming a shortcut is easy (if you don't know: select the shortcut and press "F2", you can now edit the text of the shortcut).

Comment: Changing the icon is equally simple, although a little bit more work. First rightclick the shortcut and then select properties, then click the "change icon" button, you'll end up with a whole lot of icons and a little filechooser up top. Click the "choose file" or something alike and browse to the skyrim folder, select an exe which has the icon you want. Click "open". Now the skyrim icon should be the only one in the list instead of the whole mass of default icons. Select it, and  you are done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way to use the Skyrim launcher to run SKSE. You can make a shortcut to skse_loader.exe to run it more conveniently.

Comment: You can then even rename said shortcut to "Skyrim" and change the icon of it to the skyrim icon, so the shortcut looks identical to the one created by steam.

Comment: @Arperum How would one accomplish that? Also, is there a direct way to respond to comments? (I'm rather new here)  :)

Comment: @avestar101 Make a Windows shortcut of `skse_loader.exe` (use the right-click menu). Drag it anywhere you want. Right-click the shortcut and pick "Properties". There are icon changing options in there. Find a suitable icon file by using a search engine, or by just pointing the icon-choosing file dialogue at the Skyrim executable.

Comment: Check my answer below. There is a way to make the Skyrim launcher run SKSE.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following to make the Skyrim Launcher launch with SKSE:

1. Go into your Skyrim folder.
2. Rename TESV.exe (the application that launches Skyrim) to Skyrim.exe, and skse_loader.exe to TESV.exe. This "tricks" the launcher into thinking that it is loading Skyrim where it is, in fact, loading the SKSE loader that then loads Skyrim.
3. Go into your Data folder, then the skse folder. If it doesn't exist, create it.
4. Make a file named skse.ini using notepad, and in it, put the following down:

> ```
> [Loader]
> RuntimeName = Skyrim.exe
> ```

5. Save the file, and run Skyrim using the Skyrim Launcher.

Side note: If Nexus Mod Manager notifies you that SKSE isn't installed, ignore the warnings and install the mod. This is because NMM checks for SKSE by checking if there is a skse_loader.exe file in the Skyrim folder. And obviously, as you renamed it, it is not there.

Comment: I mean, copy it and rename it? That would fix the NMM notification, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this 3rd party launcher](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/9413) to add options like SKSE and others to the launcher.