# Skyrim character freezing repeatedly

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I'm in Korvanjund on the Jagged Crown quest, and my character has started freezing up randomly.

By 'freezing', I mean: my character will suddenly stop, sheathe weapons and then just stand frozen in the idle pose. I can't use inventory/magic/favourites menus, I can't move or draw my weapons. I *can* use the quest menu and move the camera.

The other NPCs on the quest continue to move, and fight enemies, but enemies ignore me completely (even if I was fighting one when it happened).

This is the first time this has ever happened, and I've been using this character and set of mods for a while. The first time it happened I had been playing for an hour or so, but when I load a save it happens shortly after loading (almost immediately to a few minutes).

Any ideas? The wiki pages for this area and quest don't list it as a known bug. Is there a console code I could use to reset myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling a variety of different search terms eventually brought me to [this thread](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/994738-random-cinematic-sequence-freezes-character/) where someone had, through a process of elimination, identified **vibMUTEXSCT.pex** in the scripts folder as the culprit.

Moving this file out of the folder allowed me to finish the quest, though I still need to work out which mod this file is from to disable it.

Edit: turned out to be **Immersive Beds**. (I worked this out by scrolling through my mod list in Wrye Bash looking at the file list in the right-hand pane for each)

Comment: Could you link to the thread you found in this answer, and could you also list your mods in your question? This is to help other users who have encountered the same issue. Also, maybe we could find the mod which included the culprit file that way.

Comment: Added link to thread; mods will have to wait til I get home. Is there a file which will contain a copy-and-pasteable list anywhere? So I don't have to type it out?

Comment: You can copy-paste the mod list in [plugins.txt](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/109770/4797). You can also use [BOSS](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/6) to list your mods. You can copy-paste its output.

Answer (score 4):

Try these fixes (from the [UESP Wiki, "Skyrim - Glitches" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Glitches)):

> #### Getting Stuck
>
> - Sometimes, you will become stuck after a cinematic dialogue. Use the [console command](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console), [`enableplayercontrols`](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29#Player_commands) to retain your controls.
> - Rarely, it is possible to get stuck between objects, and be unable to move. This can be solved by fast traveling or using the [console commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console), [`coc <cellname>`](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#Untargeted_Commands) or [`tcl`](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#Toggle_Commands).

Comment: That was a good suggestion but unfortunately didn't help. After `enableplayercontrols` I could draw/sheathe my weapon and use the menus, but still couldn't move! Thanks anyway though