# My game crashes only in select locations

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

So, in the last few days I've been revisiting Skyrim, one of my favorite games, and trying to do a serious RP playthrough of the game (no fast travel, open cities mod, taking a journal, etc.)

Unfortunately for me, this became 20x harder for me yesterday, when I discovered walking toward Falkreath that my game crashes in two places that are essential to be passed on the way to the city. One is the large lake just north of it, and the road from Helgen to Falkreath. I tried to bypass the large trip by road to Falkreath by going to the hunter's camp behind the Guardian Stones, then proceeding to swim around the corner onto the land farther south of that.

I then discovered that that area causes me to crash (I've tested it, it's like an axes which crashes the game once I pass it). So, I decided the trip through Helgen would be fine.

As I continued down that road, I found it crashes in an area on that road. Same situation, trying to walk around causes the same thing. Every time I neared that point, there was a Redguard warrior standing still there, making me suspect he was a maliciously bugged NPC. I discovered he was not the problem as he came forward of the line to kill a skeleton that had randomly spawned. I neared him, and didn't crash. I proceeded to kill him (just in case) and walked west to that line, and it crashed again. I've tried deactivating certain mods, as well as sleeping a week hoping the cells would reset, and while they did, it did not affect the places of crash.

I made a new game and deleted all of the save games that I believed were corrupted. This was not the case. As soon as I escaped Helgen I headed to the Guardian Stones with Hadvar and then went the exact same route around the hunter's camp I originally took, to discover that the game still crashed in that location.

After that, I decided the only way to fix it was to delete the game and reinstall it. After doing that I walked to the area causing my game to crash, to no avail. I'd highly appreciate some help or guidance. Thanks!

My Mod List:

Open Cities Skyrim

SkyUI

ESP Craftable Clothes

Skooma

Scenic Carriages

SKSE v1.7.2

All of the Unofficial Skyrim Patches

Comment: Try [configuring SKSE's `skse.ini` to run the `ClearInvalidRegistrations` command](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/92234/4797) (without other mods installed). Also, please [edit in your mod list](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/109770/4797) to the question.

Comment: I've tried finding SKSE.ini (the description of Open Cities Skyrim suggests it for CTDs, though this may not be what this is), but to no avail. I've enabled hidden files, but it still doesn't appear. How do I find it? Also, I posted it. Thanks for helping me out with the formatting and such.

Comment: Try creating `skse.ini` using a text editor and place it under the `\Skyrim\Data\SKSE\` directory. It should contain the text I described [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/92234/4797).

Comment: When you say "using a text editor," you don't mean a special program I wouldn't already have in Windows 7? (I apologize for my amateur questions. I'm just starting to learn about this computer.)

Comment: By 'text editor', I mean Notepad or a similar program.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Now, should this be under the App Data folder or the SteamApps folder?

Comment: Under 'steamapps' ('Skyrim' directory where `skse_loader.exe` is located, if SKSE is installed correctly). Note that `skse_loader.exe` must be used to launch Skyrim for the `skse.ini` tweak to work.

Comment: I did it! I'm so proud of myself! Unfortunately, it didn't work... The console command was entered, works, and reported there were no OnUpdate problems. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try removing all mods and see if it still crashes. If it does, it's gonna be a little tricky to troubleshoot as it may have been an effect of a mod that you had installed (even if you already removed it). Try asking at forum posts discussing the mods you have installed.